# Error: Thread creation failed: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have deployed my Rails application on server.

It is working fine, but it crashed on sign_up page and server will be stop.

I Checked my mongrel.log file, it give the following error.

libgomp: Thread creation failed: Cannot allocate memory

How can I resolved this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what. Your server is OOM.